# OAuth2.0 with @react-oauth/google: Getting 403 Error Despite Correct ClientId and IP Whitelisting

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I'm currently working on implementing OAuth2.0 in my React application using the @react-oauth/google library. However, I've encountered a 403 error when attempting to connect. I've ensured that my application's IP is added to the allowed list, and the ClientId is correctly specified.

Here are the key details:

Library in Use: @react-oauth/google

Error: 403 Forbidden

Details: I've added my application's IP to the allowed list, and the ClientId is accurate.

Wrapped application code:

```
createRoot(root).render(
  <RootModelContextProvider>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={googleClientId}>
        <Main />
      </GoogleOAuthProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </RootModelContextProvider>,
);
```

Function to add authorization button through google:

```
  return useGoogleOneTapLogin({
    onSuccess: (credentialResponse) => {
      console.log(credentialResponse);
    },
    onError: () => {
      console.log('Login Failed');
    },
  });
```

Screenshot of allowed ip in Google Cloud:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem solved itself when I added http://localhost to the list of white IPs
[image]